# Alt key sticks sometimes in remote desktop session

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, xfce, modifier-keys

I'm running a Linux VM on windows with Hyper-V and connect via a remote desktop session. It often happens that the Alt-key appears to remain pressed after I use a keyboard shortcut involving both, Alt and Shift. If I press Alt again, everything works fine but it is pretty annoying because various keyboard shortcuts are triggered when I continue typing without pressing Alt again after the initial shortcut that causes the problem.

The problem is not related to a specific application but is reproducible in different apps.

I'm using the xfce desktop and xrdp.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but did you ever solve it? I'm running into the same exact thing myself: whenever I press Alt+Shift, the Alt key gets stuck "on", so that all keypresses are effectively Alt+{whatever}, until I hit Alt again. (For reference, I'm using centos 7, Gnome Shell, tigervnc-server, xrdp, and Remote Desktop Connection on Windows 7.)

Comment: @KenBellows no, at least I don't remember. Fortunately, I don't have to work on a windows machine anymore ;-)

Comment: I have the same problem using windows -> windows remote desktop

Comment: Probably not your issue, but there is a bug in xrdp which causes this Redhat 7 - https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1415069

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you have sticky keys on.  Pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> 5 times turns it on.  Uncheck the setting on this page[image].

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the problem. It's turned off as in your screenshot.

Comment: @lex82, it may not be your problem, but in my screenshot it is on.  "Turn on Sticky Keys when Shift is pressed five times" is actually ticked.

Comment: I thought the first checkbox would override it because of the indentation but I had also tried deactivating all of the boxes.

Comment: No, try it.  Press shift 5 times.

Comment: Ok, you are right. However, unfortunately it does not solve the problem.